# DiscordJS + NodeJS: SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)

Tags: node.js, json, discord.js, setinterval

Having an issue where I will randomly get this error after about an hour of my code running.

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Here is my code:

```
function matchMaking() {
    setInterval(function() {

        fs.readFile('./rankedQueue.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            const file = JSON.parse(data); //The line the error occurs

            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                //lots of code here
            }
        })
    }, 10 * 1000)
}
```

edit: This is the content of the JSON file.

```
    {
    "queue": [],
    "waiting": [],
    "lowLevel": [],
    "placeHolder": [
        {
            "test": "test"
        }
    ]
}
```

The arrays are being pushed to, and then spliced a couple times a minute.

After searching here and some forums, I've tried using fs.readFileSync, which makes the code not run at all. And now I'm finding some specific examples of this error that I can't quite seem to make the solutions apply to me. If anyone has any idea of what I should be changing, It would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It sounds as if you are reading the file while it is half-written by another application. If you don't have control over the other application then I'd simply catch the "unexpected end of json input" error, wait a few seconds and retry, possible several times. If you do have control over it then I'd change it so it writes to another temporary file and then only when done deletes the old one and renames the temp file. There is still a race condition to consider between delete and rename but the window could be shorter. But it would be best to use some sort of IPC instead of a file.

Comment: (I don't think the json file you posted is really what's in the file when it fails, maybe do `fs.writeFile('badfile.txt', data)` in your `catch` and then inspect `badfile.txt` after it failed again to see what exactly the program "saw" there that was invalid JSON.)

Answer (score 0):

As the errors said data is not in json type
Can you make sure the file is valid and it's is what `JSON.parse()` can parse

Comment: Sorry. The post has been edited to include the contents of the JSON file.

Comment: If this is json file I think you can import it directly without need `JSON.parse();`

Comment: No because that would cache the results and would be synchronous.

Answer (score -1):

## How to use fs.readFileSync

Using `fs.readFileSync` returns a `buffer`. You can easily convert the buffer into something readable. You use `buffer.toString('ascii')`. Also, `fs.readFile` has a callback argument while readFileSync **DOESN'T**. What I think you were doing about `readFileSync` was:

```js
       fs.readFileSync('./rankedQueue.json', 'utf8', function(err, data) {
            const file = JSON.parse(data); //The line the error occurs

            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                //lots of code here
            }
        })
```

But you should actually be doing this:

```js
       var data = fs.readFileSync('./rankedQueue.json');
       var JSON = JSON.parse(data.toString('ascii'));
```

You could drop the `'ascii'`.

## Incorrect / Hacky Answer

Use `require` instead. Node.JS has it so it can parse a `JSON` file for you. Keep in mind that the way you require a file compared to `fs` is different.

If your code is located at `/project/foobar/code.js`
JSON is at `/project/rankedQueue.json`

`fs` automatically goes to the top of where your project folder is, e.g. `/project` & So `./rankedQueue.json`

`require` does not do this, and stays in the folder where the file is. You have to add `../` for every folder you want to go above. So: `./../rankedQueue.json`.

I'd suggest also running your `JSON` through a validator as well so it can tell you whats wrong.

Comment: But require will cache the result and hence that won't work for the user's ever-changing file. Plus, require is synchronous and blocks execution, so it's not a good solution.

Comment: +CherryDT to solve the caching issue that's simply `delete require.cache[require.resolve('directory')]`

Comment: Yes but why would you create a problem to then hackishly fix it? The OP is already using the right approach for reading data files (that aren't part of the repository): `fs.readFile` and `JSON.parse`.

Comment: +CherryDT, I just figured out another way to do it so I'll update my post right now.